# Save results in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

```
score.sentiment <- function(sentences, valence1, .progress='none')
{
  require(plyr)
  require(stringr)
  sentence <- tolower(sentence) #to lower case
  val.matches1 <- str_count(sentence, valence1) #find words in dictionary
  return(val.matches1)
}
final_scores <- matrix('', 0, 20)
for(i in mytxtfiles){
  print(i)
  tryCatch(
    {
      sentence <- readLines(i, warn = FALSE)
      sentence <- paste(sentence, collapse = ' ')
      #Uses the created function to assign dictionary scores to texts
      positive <- score.sentiment(sentence, valence1, .progress='text') 
      filename<-i
      result<-cbind(filename,positive)
      final_scores <- rbind(final_scores, result)
    }, 
    error=function(e){}
  )
}
```

If I do print(positive) in my for loop, I have :

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I would like to save the output of my function into a dataframe, then row binding it each time it loops through a text, and ending up with a database with one column for the filename and 19 column for the output of str_count, but somehow my dataframe is empty at the end of the process. Any helps appreciated.

**EDIT**

Using "val.matches1 <- (t(val.matches1))" in my function, I transpose the column with 19 rows into one row and 19 columns. How can I add them to my dataframe ?

Comment: after the for-loop write `final_scores`.

Answer (score 0):

To update the dataframe with values inside a loop and without the overhead associated with repeatedly calling bind, define the data frame outside the loop with the proper size and then assign values row by row.

Since I don't know what variable "mytxtfiles" represents, I was not able to test this but it should point you in the correct direction.  See comments for an explanation.

```
mylength <- length(mytxtfiles)
#initialize the dataframe to the desired length
final_scores <- data.frame(filename = character(length=mylength), positive = vector(length=mylength))
#initialize the index
index <-0

for(i in mytxtfiles){
   print(i)
   tryCatch(
      {
         sentence <- readLines(i, warn = FALSE)
         sentence <- paste(sentence, collapse = ' ')
         #Uses the created function to assign dictionary scores to texts
         positive <- score.sentiment(sentence, valence1, .progress='text') 
         #increment the index and store the values
         index <- index +1
         final_scores[index, "filename"]<- i
         final_scores[index, "positive"]<- positive
      }, 
      error=function(e){}
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the "positive" column returns "FALSE". Investigating further I think "Positive" is saved as a column variable with multiple rows rather than the oposite.. Would you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: Edit: using "val.matches1 <- (t(val.matches1))" in my function, I transpose the column with 19 rows into one row, 19 columns. 
How can I add them to my dataframe ?

Comment: There are several other potential solutions depending on the size of your initial dataset and how frequency you need to execute this script.  It is hard to provide a specific answer to a non-reproducible question. Use one can assign a vector to multiple columns like this: `final_scores[1, 2:3] <- c(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
map_dcf(valence1, function(valence1){
tibble(!!sym(valence1) := sapply(sentence, str_count, pattern=valence1))
}) %>% mutate(file=i)
```

Ended up doing this.